# Prevent method calls for n seconds, show message of the remaining time

Tags: python, events, time, tkinter, bind

I'm working on simple GUI but I'm stuck. This is the basic flow:

1. Show text `text` and:

   - save time in `time_pressed`
   - start the `progressbar` and update it until `time_notallow` expires.
2. If a user presses `<Next>` see if seconds specified in `time_notallow` have passed,
   and if not, don't allow the display of the next `text`.

Basically, I want to prevent users form calling a method bind to the `<Right>` key until `time_notallow` passes, and show a progressbar to inform them how long they'll have to wait. Since I use `bind`, such as...

```
    self.master.bind('<Right>', self.text_next)
```

...I don't have `.after()`, as in widgets.

#### What I've tried

1. `master.after()` to set `bind` to `None` and after `time_notallow` to `bind` to `self.text_next`, but it didn't work.
2. Created a `thread` which looped with `while True` to check constantly if `time_notallow` is passed or not, but the application crashes.

Any help appreciated.

#### Edit: A Solution. Using `lambda()` in `.after` to count seconds (thanks to  Bryan Oakley)

```
"""

Stripped-down version to figue out time/event/threading stuff.

What this has to do:

1. Show the window and some text.
2. User presses Next arrow and new text shows. Paint the label red.
3. Prevent user form pressing again (unbind all keys), until 2 seconds passed 
   (time_wait).
4. Make notice of passed time and after 2 seconds bind the keys again and
   paint the label green.
5. Loop the steps 2-4.

"""

import sys
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import W, E, S, N

class Test(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        """Draw the GUI"""
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.draw_widgets()
        self.grid()
        self.time_wait = 2
        self.locked = False
        self.bind_keys()
        self.counter = 0

    def draw_widgets(self):
        """Draw all the widgets on the frame."""
        text = 'Just a sample sentence.'
        #Label with the sentence
        self.lbl_text = tk.Label(self, anchor="center", relief='groove')
        self.lbl_text['text'] = text
        self.lbl_text['font'] = ('Helvetica', 27)
        self.lbl_text.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=W+E+S+N)
        self.lbl_note = tk.Label(self, anchor="center", relief='groove',
            bg='green')
        self.lbl_note.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=W+E+S+N)

    def text_next(self, event):
        """Get next text"""
        if not self.locked:
            self.counter += 1
            self.lbl_text['text'] = 'The text number %s!' % self.counter
            self.bind_tonone()
            self.lock(self.time_wait)

    def text_previous(self, event):
        """Get previous text"""
        if not self.locked:
            self.counter -= 1
            self.lbl_text['text'] = 'The text number %s!' % self.counter
            self.bind_tonone()
            self.lock(self.time_wait)

    def bind_keys(self):
        """Bind the keys"""
        self.master.bind('<Left>', self.text_previous)
        self.master.bind('<Right>', self.text_next)
        self.master.bind('<Escape>', self.exit)
        self.lbl_note['bg'] = 'green'

    def bind_tonone(self):
        """Unbind the keys"""
        self.master.bind('<Left>', None)
        self.master.bind('<Right>', None)
        self.master.bind('<Escape>', None)
        self.lbl_note['bg'] = 'red'

    def lock(self, n):
        if n == 0:
            self.locked = False
            self.lbl_note['text'] = ''
            self.lbl_note['bg'] = 'green'

        else:
            self.locked = True
            self.lbl_note['text'] = 'Locked for %s more seconds' % n
            self.lbl_note.after(1000, lambda n = n - 1: self.lock(n))

    def exit(self, event):
        """Exit the program."""
        sys.exit()

def start():
    """Start the gui part."""
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = Test(master=root)
    app.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need threads or timers to solve this problem. All you need is a procedure that takes a number of seconds to wait, and have it call itself once a second until the number gets down to zero.

It would look something like this (off the top of my head, untested):

```
def __init__(...):
    ...
    self.locked = False
    ...

def text_next(self, event):
    if not self.locked:
        <do the "next" logic>
        self.lock(10) # lock for 10 seconds

def text_previous(self, event):
    if not self.locked:
        <do the "previous" logic>
        self.lock(10) # lock for 10 seconds

def lock(self, n):
    if n == 0:
        self.locked = False
        self.status.config(text="")
    else:
        self.locked = True
        self.status.config(text="Locked for %s more seconds" % n)
        self.status.after(1000, lambda n=n-1: self.lock(n))
```

Comment: It works perfectly. Very elegant. Btw, this is the first time I've had `lambda` in my code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How about instead of a spin-waiting thread, you try the specifically-designed [`threading.Timer`](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#timer-objects) object?

Comment: Thanks. I tried, but I can't stop the Timer: next time the user presses the key, it causes error (Timer can't be started twice).

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix using your timer is to refactor a bit. Set your self.track initially to None, then only set it to run/block on  arrow.

```
import sys
import threading
import Tkinter as tk
from Tkinter import W, E, S, N

class Test(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        """Draw the GUI"""
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.draw_widgets()
        self.grid()
        # Track wait times
        self.time_wait = 2
        # Timer
        self.track = None
        self.bind_keys()
        self.counter = 0

    def draw_widgets(self):
        """Draw all the widgets on the frame."""
        text = 'Just a sample sentence.'
        #Label with the sentence
        self.lbl_text = tk.Label(self, anchor="center", relief='groove')
        self.lbl_text['text'] = text
        self.lbl_text['font'] = ('Helvetica', 27)
        self.lbl_text.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=W+E+S+N)
        self.lbl_note = tk.Label(self, anchor="center", relief='groove',
            bg='green')
        self.lbl_note.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=W+E+S+N)

    def text_next(self, event):
        """Get next text"""
        if not self.track or not self.track.is_alive():
            self.track = threading.Timer(self.time_wait, self.bind_keys)
            self.counter += 1
            self.lbl_text['text'] = 'The text number %s!' % self.counter
            self.bind_tonone()
            self.track.start()

    def text_previous(self, event):
        """Get previous text"""
        self.counter -= 1
        self.lbl_text['text'] = 'The text number %s!' % self.counter

    def bind_keys(self):
        """Bind the keys"""
        self.master.bind('<Left>', self.text_previous)
        self.master.bind('<Right>', self.text_next)
        self.master.bind('<Escape>', self.exit)
        self.lbl_note['bg'] = 'green'

    def bind_tonone(self):
        """Unbind the keys"""
        self.master.bind('<Left>', None)
        self.master.bind('<Right>', None)
        self.master.bind('<Escape>', None)
        self.lbl_note['bg'] = 'red'

    def exit(self, event):
        """Exit the program."""
        sys.exit()

def start():
    """Start the gui part."""
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = Test(master=root)
    app.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start()
```

On preview though, @Bryan Oakley, has a better solution.